# perl - Facebook Graph - Post to Fanpage

Tags: facebook, perl, facebook-graph-api

this is not giving me any errors but yet it is not posting to my fanpage wall.
would love some help in this! trying to figure this out on my own has been a roller coaster.

tested with the correct token of course.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use open qw(:std :utf8);
use LWP::Simple;
use YAML::Tiny;
use JSON;
use URI;
use utf8;

my $access_token = 'blah';
my $profile_id = '200117706712975';

#Publish to a facebook page as admin
graph_api('/' . $profile_id . '/feed',{
        access_token => $access_token,
        message => 'this is a test!',
        link => 'http://test.com',
        method => 'post'
});

exit 0;

sub graph_api {
  my $uri = new URI('https://graph.facebook.com/' . shift);
  $uri->query_form(shift);
  my $resp = get("$uri");
  return defined $resp ? decode_json($resp) : undef;
}
```

Comment: You may try visit https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer and REPLACE your access token(used by perl script above) to the access token field. Then select a POST request, set message field, and POST to 200117706712975/feed. This can prove both your token and API is exactly work, narrow the possible causes.

Answer (score 1):

If you dump the response object - $resp - using Data::Dumper is similar, you will get the reason for the post not appearing.  The response object is JSON.